# Error in paperclip gem in rails v 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

hello I'm new to rails I wanted to upload the image using paperclip gem in my form but it is showing me the error.

```
1 error prohibited this cuber from being saved:
Gravatar translation missing:en.activerecord.errors.models.cuber.attributes.gravatar.spoofed_media_type
```

I had bundled the gem of latest version from git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git and also version 3.5.3 in both I'm getting this error
still it shows error
my cuber.rb file is

```
class Cuber < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :gravatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :gravatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

my form is

```
<%= form_for @cuber , :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @cuber.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@cuber.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cuber from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @cuber.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
   </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.file_field :gravatar %>

 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :name %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
<%= f.label :surname %><br>
<%= f.text_field :surname %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It says 'spoofed_media_type', makes me think there is something wrong with your 'content_type' setting, try removing the validation to start

Comment: get the paperclip latest version, gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git" will get the latest.

Comment: I had bundled the latest thoughtbot git but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

`validates_attachment_content_type :gravatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/` was only introduced in [Paperclip V4](http://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip)

Prior to this release, you don't need the content type validation. I'd recommend upgrading to Paperclip V4, and this error should resolve